# Android Program Error Connecting

Tags: java, android

Ultimately, my goal is to get an Android app that receives an XML file from a URL, parses it, and displays the relevant information (well, the final goal is a lot more complex than that, but that is the current goal).  I'm using examples from "Beginning Android Application Development" by Wei-Meng Lee, and I've noticed some errors in the book's sample code already (particularly a misname variable, if Eclipse hadn't pointed it out I would have missed it completely).

Currently, however, the app is not able to connect to the internet, despite having permission, having access (3g, 4g, and wifi have all been tested), and being able to reach the test URL in the on-board browser.

Here are the relevant code snippets.  Am I doing anything wrong?  (note: I tested both in an emulator and on my Galaxy S2)

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = 01;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("Get");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}
```

I have tried different URLs, checking that I can connect to each of them in the phone's browser before using them.  The Emulator didn't have any luck either.

UPDATE: The asynch code that utilizes the below:

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask
<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url){
        // download an image
        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(url[0]);
        return bitmap;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Method call for above:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new BackgroundTask().execute("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif");

}
```

Comment: is this being done in an `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an AsyncTask for anything requiring a network connection. You can setup your Async as follows: (This takes a String as a parameter and returns an InputStream)

```
public class OpenHttpConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String urlstring = params[0];
      InputStream in = null;
      int response = 01;

      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

      if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
      try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("Get");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
      }
      return in;

    }

}
```

Then you can call/run you Async like this.

```
OpenHttpConnection connection = new OpenHttpConnection().execute("http://YourURL.com");
InputStream is = connection.get();
```